# Find out last not blank value in Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to get excel to show me the last not blank value in an excel table but it gives me an error whenever I type in the formula.

So I found this formula over here and on other different sources:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""), A:A)
```

I've changed the ranges (`A:A`) with those I need but it still gives me an error and doesn't let me type it in.

Has it something to do with the fact that the values in the fields (in the table) are in "Time" format?

Comment: What is the formula after you changed it?

Comment: =LOOKUP(2,1/(G4:G34<>""),G4:G34)  <--- like this in my case

Comment: Now what error is being returned?

Comment: Is the worksheet in xlR1C1 mode?

Comment: Excel shows me the standard error ... : There is a problem with your formula... You don't want to type in a formula ? .... etc. etc.

Comment: The cell with the formula is on standard right now, but was on "Time" ... I tried several formats but it didn't work

Comment: Nope, I don't know about that mode. Never heard of it ... It's a simple excel sheet

Comment: Have you tried in a different cell, Typing, not copy/paste, the formula from scratch.  Maybe you have something in the formula that is not visible.

Comment: Do you usually use `;` instead of `,` as the parameter separator in Excel formulas?

Comment: When I do that, it shows me no error but, also not the value of the last cell with a value ... just a " #Name?

Comment: Well, not it shows #Value!  ---> (translated back into english)

Comment: What is the actual formula, in your language you are using?

Comment: It's called "Verweis"

Comment: Can you post the full formula you are using.  As far as I can see `=VERWEIS(2;1/(G4:G34<>"");G4:G34)` should work (but I am using Chrome to try and translate the [page](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/VERWEIS-Funktion-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb?ui=de-DE&rs=de-DE&ad=DE) so I might be reading it wrong)

Comment: This is what I enter in excel : =VERWEIS(2,1/(G4:G34<>"");G4:G34) 

... the table contains values in the fomrat of time...

Comment: Oh, I've got the problem ... found it out

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K :)

Comment: Yes - **ALL** `,`s need to be changed to `;` - LOL

Comment: Don't know how I oversee it haha